# Java Array returning as two-dimensional

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to do a Kata on Codewars in Java that asks "you have decided to write a function that will return the first n elements of the sequence with the given common difference *step* and first element *first*." Below I have done what is asked, but when I return the final array it returns as two-dimensional (like [[1, 2, 3, 4]] instead of [1, 2, 3, 4]). Please help me understand why and how to fix this!

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Progression {

    public static String arithmeticSequenceElements(int first, int step, 
    long total) {
    int[] intArr;
    intArr = new int [(int)total];
    intArr[0] = first;
    int i = 1;
    while(i<total){
      intArr[i] = intArr[i-1] + step;
      i++;
    }
    return Arrays.toString(intArr);
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the platform isn't adding the other set of `[]`? Because that output isn't possible with the code shown.

Comment: @Kayaman I guess that may be possible, though I've done tons of these tasks on codewars and so far their compiler hasn't changed the type of output

Comment: I could not reproduce it: https://ideone.com/dvhGW0. How are you sure the output is `"[[1, 2, 3, 4]]"`? I get `"[1, 2, 3, 4]"`.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @lexicore I'm sure the output is [[1, 2, 3, 4]] because when I "attempt" the task (tell the site I want to run the code and see if I get the expected answer) it says: expected:<[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]> but was:<[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platform is expecting you to return just the values `1, 2, 3, 4`.

You're returning the default `Arrays.toString()` representation which is `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. The platform then displays it as `<[[1, 2, 3, 4]]>`.

You could return just the elements with for example

```
String str = Arrays.toString(intArr);
return str.substring(1, str.length()-1);
```

Comment: Aha, this makes sense. But how would I go about returning the values in the array without returning the array itself? probably a noob question but im not great at Java :[

Comment: this worked! thank you so much. very easy to understand once you made me realize it just wanted to strings alone :D